# JavaScript Not Working with HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a simple registration form with basic `HTML` and `PHP` to insert data to my database. Basically, I want to validate the fields first before inserting the data and so I have created an external `JavaScript` file. Problem is, it is displaying the actual `JavaScript` code on the next page as opposed to validating!

**My HTML file:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register Page</title>
<body>
<form id="register" method="POST" action="register.js" onsubmit="return verify()" action="register.php">
    Forename: <input type="text" name="forename"><br>
    Lastname: <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

**My JavaScript file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verify(){
        var forename = document.getElementById["forename"].value;
        if(forename == null || forename == ""){
            alert("Forename is empty");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Instead of just validating I'm being redirected to a new webpage showing me the code I have written above.

I am completely new to web development and it would mean a lot if someone could help me out. All I want to do is just validate the fields before adding them to the database.

Comment: `action="register.js"` that won't work. You also have `action="register.php"` so remove the js one.

Comment: Then how do I run the script??

Answer (score 1):

Two things you have to change

add id to your input control because you are fetching the value of text through Id

```
<input type="text" name="forename" id="forename">
```

syntax of getElementById()

```
var forename = document.getElementById("forename").value;
```

Once You do the validation for username and password. Submit the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function verify(){
        var forename = document.getElementById("forename").value;
        if(forename == null || forename == ""){
            alert("Forename is empty");
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>


<form id="register" method="POST" onsubmit="return verify()" action="register.php">
Forename: <input type="text" id="forename"><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Where do I write that. Sorry, could you please edit my javascript code if possible because I am so lost at the moment

Comment: you have to submit the form after the validations.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Sorry

Comment: My javascript doesnt work, nothing works - this web dev sucks

Comment: Once you submit the form it willl go to register.php page because you have mentioned in action

Comment: I suggest you to study some tutorials first in web development

Comment: Thanks. Just two things. One how would I do it if the `JavaScript` file was external, i.e not on the same `html` page and also how do I have a message box appear in the middle for errors?

Comment: <script src="URL">  The URL of the external script file. you are using the inbuilt function of browser i.e alert() . In Internet Explorer it will come in middle however in chrome it will come on the top. You have to create your own popup if you want in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should recheck your syntax for document.getElementById["forename"]

It should be document.getElementById("forename")

You can try debugging step wise. For example, try console.log.

```
var forename = document.getElementById("forename").value;

console.log(forename);
```

Try Chrome/Firebox Inspect element > Console and see if anything is been printed.

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Did you try that console thing? Or simply write alert(forename) and see if it's able to retrieve any value.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be declaring register.js as the `action` for your `<form>`. The action attribute of a `<form>` element tells the browser where to send (`POST` or `GET`) the form data to, which is why you're being taken to register.js in your browser.

You need to intercept the browser submitting the form, do your validation, and then send the data on to your PHP file (register.php). It might be worth reading some tutorials on javascript form validation, such as [this TutorialsPoint one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm).

Answer (score 0):

What you can be able to do is to take your hole script into a echo in php, then create a php validation for the js and check if js got successfully done then execute script if so.

Answer (score -1):

if you want your javascript on same html page then put this type

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Register Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function verify(){
    var forename = document.getElementById["forename"].value;
    if(forename == null || forename == ""){
        alert("Forename is empty");
        return false;
    }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="register" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return    verify()" action="register.php">
Forename: <input type="text" name="forename"><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="surname"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah but then what happens if you want it on a separate file? Also how do you add to the database AFTER validating?